# PHP regular expression for numbers and commas only

Tags: php, regex

I need to create a regular expression to validate comma separated numeric values.

They should look like: 1,2,3,4,5 etc....

The value must be either a single digit like: 1 no empty spaces before or after, no commas before or after.

Or... multiple numerical values separated by commas. First and last characters must be a number.

I have the following code but it only checks for numbers and commas in no particular order:

How can I change the regular expression below to fit the above description?

Thank you!

```
// get posted value
if(isset($_POST['posted_value']))
{
    $sent_value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST['posted_value']));
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9,]+$/', $posted_value))
    {
        $what_i_need = $posted_value;
    }
    else
    {
        $msg .= $not_what_i_need;
    }
}
else
{
    $msg .= $posted_value_not_set;
}
```

Comment: Just to give a reason for the edit, you were saying [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma) when you meant [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^\d(?:,\d)*$/
```

Explanation:

```
/            # delimiter
  ^          # match the beginning of the string
  \d         # match a digit
    (?:      # open a non-capturing group
      ,      # match a comma
      \d     # match a digit
    )        # close the group
    *        # match the previous group zero or more times
  $          # match the end of the string
/            # delimiter
```

If you allow multi-digit numbers, then change `\d` to `\d+`.

Comment: For multi-digit numbers use /^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/

Answer (score 2):

Do you allow the user to input numbers with commas in them, like `5,000` for example? what about decimals like `5.6`?

Alternatively you could validate the input using explode something like this.

```
$values = explode(',',$sent_value);
$valid = true;

foreach($values as $value) {
    if(!ctype_digit($value)) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
```